# Selecting an image for an object

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I want to give user a possibility to select an image/icon for every object from list. Can i create a context menu with images which pop-up on click or do I have to make separate activity with listview of images?

Comment: Use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html).

Comment: I am currently working on separate activity with listview.